# Using WildCard Sub-Domains in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a shop blog system and every user can have a shop with its `"username + main domain"` Domain. For example if main domain is `"Stranger.com"` then user1 will have `"user1.Stranger.com"`

I need to control users via global.asax like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower().StartsWith("user1."))
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Pages/user1.aspx", true);
}
```

First question is how can I set wildcard subdomains (*.stranger.com) on IIS
and Second question is that Am I in a right way controlling URL in global.asax?

Comment: To me that looks like each sub domain per user and that would require domain dns update every time a new user emerge...

Comment: @Oluwafemi thanks, what about second part, I heard I must use routing for this purpose but it seems my piece of code is right and will do the job?!?

Comment: To my best understanding, the code you have above should do the job. However, there other alternative is to setup the database to return the relevant URL per user via the domain name for maintainability purposes.

Comment: Only IIS 10 supports wildcard in host name. You will have to wait for Windows Server 2016. Or you switch to Microsoft Azure.